# AngularJS - Is it possible to compile and link template from code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I make the following code append **2** to the document?

```
var $injector = angular.injector(['ng']);

$injector.invoke(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
    var link = $compile('<p>{{1+1}}</p>');
    var newElement = link($rootScope);

    $(document.body).append(newElement);
});
```

What I now see in browser is

```
{{1+1}}
```

**EDIT**

I want the added to body element, not just be interpolated static HTML, but to be an angular app - so that it reflects changes in scope, has event handlers, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You need that to be bound to the `$scope` rather than `$rootScope`, change the line to

```
function ctrl($scope) {
    var $injector = angular.injector(['ng']);

    $injector.invoke(function ($compile) {
        var link = $compile('<p>{{1+1}}</p>');
        var newElement = link($scope);
        $(document.body).append(newElement);
    });
}
```

Or, you can use [$interpolate](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.%24interpolate) module.

```
function ctrl($scope, $interpolate) {
    var $injector = angular.injector(['ng']);
    $injector.invoke(function ($compile) {
        var link = '<p>{{1+1}}</p>';
        var exp = $interpolate(link)({});
        $(document.body).append(exp);
    });
}
```

Comment: How about if I change rootscope property to make it reflect to what I append to the document. I mean I need not just interpolated HTML, but a working app, that is bound to scope and has events/etc?